# Print plain JSON content to html page in Javascript / jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

After getting an HTTP response in the form a JSON file, how can I handle its plain content using jQuery?

I've done this before, but I just can't figure out how right now.

I'm using this function to retrieve the JSON content.

```
var json = $.getJSON("test.json",  
   function(response){
           // do stuff
       }
);
```

Of course, I can handle the data contained in the JSON, but I'd like to handle and print its plain content, like this:

```
{"name": "Pepe","age" : "20"}
```

The following

```
alert(response);
```

Just gives me [object Object]

And this

```
alert(jQuery.parseJSON(json));
```

Just gives me null

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I'm pretty new to all this, so I must be using the wrong search terms, because it looks like a trivial matter.

Comment: Try `console.log` instead of `alert` because it allows you to see what's inside the object.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock console.log only works if you _have a console available_ and in some IE versions it does not allow you to see what's inside. Use `JSON.stringify(json)` to convert it to plain text.

Comment: A browser with a console is necessary for javascript development period.

Comment: @Austin I wouldn't dream of it either, but when doing something that is targeted at certain browsers it can be impossible to replicate or debug in others. Like when being forced to use IE for ActiveX object, etc.

Comment: All IE versions back to 5 have a console log, which dates back to quirks mode in the 90s. No browser worth supporting will be too old to have a console. Just my 2¢

Comment: @Austin I said "in some IE versions it does not allow you to see what's inside" Aka, even in the console you will see `[object Object]` and not the contents so it is useless here.

Comment: Nevertheless, I would not advise against using console.log just because some versions of EI will not allow for debugging. Use it for major debugging in a supported browser and then tackle the earlier versions individually with specific methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The callback to [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) actually has 3 parameters.  `data`, `textStatus` and `jqXHR`.

The [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object contains a `responseText` property that contains the raw JSON string.

```
var json = $.getJSON("test.json",  
   function(response, status, jqXHR){
           // do stuff
           console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
       }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I wanted, although my question was maybe a little misguiding. Where can I find the documentation for this? The jQuery website is a little sparse...

Comment: @broncoAbierto: The `jqXHR` object (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) is a wrapper around the native `XMLHttpRequest` object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest).

Answer (score 9):

`JSON.stringify` is probably what you want. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: This is, I think, the answer that best fits my question, although what Rocket said is actually what best fits my desires. Don't know which one to accept. Will you guys get mad if I flip a coin?

Comment: @broncoAbierto: Which ever one works better for you.  It's fine :-P

Comment: I'd actually go with what Rocket said, it's less processing for the client.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using alerts to see output, how about using the console, and then using John Resig's solution to logging this kind of data?

```
// usage: log('inside coolFunc',this,arguments);
// http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/
window.log = function(){
  log.history = log.history || [];   // store logs to an array for reference
  log.history.push(arguments);
  if(this.console){
    console.log( Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) );
  }
};
```

And then:

```
window.log(response);
```

Taken from: http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/