# Issues with printing out a json request in a blank HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

For one of the modules in my course we have to print out json results and I cannot for the life of me get this json request to print out on a blank HTML file. Is it something wrong with the code?

```
function printResults () {
    var url = "http://inserturl.com/search?app_id=123456&app_key=123456abc&format=json";
    $.getJSON(url, function(jsondata){
        // handle the results
        document.writeln(jsondata);
    });
}
```

A pointer towards the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting something back in jsondata?  Have you popped an alert to test it perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
var json = $.getJSON("test.json",  
function(response, status, jqXHR){
       // do stuff
       console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
   }
);
```

From this answer:
[Print plain JSON content to html page in Javascript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420857/print-plain-json-content-to-html-page-in-javascript-jquery) might help you out.

I tried it myself right now, and it worked just fine. You can paste in the following and see the data be printed out.

```
var json = $.getJSON("http://ipinfo.io/162.243.142.163/json",  
function(response, status, jqXHR){
    document.write(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`getJSON` or `ajax` can not load content from other domains than your own (due to cross-domain policies).

The only way to do this is to use jsonp, and that requires the service to provide solutions for that. Unless your provider has that, this will not work.

From the docs:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.
>
> Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy
>   restrictions.

Read more about jsonp in the [jQuery getJSON docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jsonp).

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the request to the URL return JSON data. Then you can use the JSON.stringify() method to serialize the JSON object into string that can be written into HTML file.

```
function printResults () {
    var url = "http://inserturl.com/search?app_id=123456&app_key=123456abc&format=json";
    $.getJSON(url, function(jsondata){
        // handle the results
        document.writeln(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
    });
}
```